# Cannot determine the field name./ addAttributeToFilter OR condition

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

How in magento i can implement OR condition when getting collection ? Currently my code looks:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('shipping_method', array("eq" => 'relay1'))
```

but ALSO i need to get orders with shipping_name relay2 so i trying next code:

```
->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute' => 'shipping_method', 'like' => 'relay1%'),
        array('attribute' => 'shipping_method', 'eq' => 'relay2'),
    )
);
```

but i get this error: **Cannot determine the field name.**

Answer (score 0):

i just need to use addFieldToFilter like this:

```
                ->addFieldToFilter(
                    array('shipping_method', 'shipping_method'),
                    array(
                        array('like'=>'mondialrelay%'),
                        array('eq'=>'beezup_beezup')
                    )
                )
```